# JMeter how to load certain group of users

Tags: jmeter

I am loading a csv file with usernames and passwords of users.
Each user belongs to a certain group eg. Group1_user1, Group1_user2,.... Group7_user1, Group7_user2 etc.

I have recorded with my Script Recorder in JMeter the HTTP requests for log in of all the users and then the steps of a HTML stepper process.
Only one group has the permission to complete a step.. there is an hierachy in the groups.
So, my question is.. since I am loading all the users, how am I going to test each step for the users who belong only to the right group?

I cant use plug-in and I cant break my Test Plan into smaller Test Plans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should be using different Thread Groups for representing different groups of logical users, so I would suggest moving at least those guys who have permission to complete a step into a separate thread group.

You can implement synchronization and passing data between thread groups if needed using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter)

If you have to stay with the single Thread Group you can use [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) or [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) to conditionally decide which step can be taken by which user.

For example if you use the following __jexl3() function as the If Controller's condition:

```
${__jexl3("${username}".contains("Group1"),)}
```

then If Controllers child(ren) will be executed only if `${username}` variable will contain `Group1`

Demo:

[image]